# Does an unknown Ikkur require a blessing?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, moshe-feinstein, ikar-tofel

This question is taking for granted the position of Reb Moshe Feinstein that a food which has two ingredients such as chocolate covered peanuts gets two brachos (blessings) being that both ingredients are desired, they are both an Ikkur (main part of the food) and not tafful(negligible part of the food).

What happens when one ingredient is unknown, such as a bowl of chocolate covered somethings. Are they peanuts in there? Raisins?

Can one now say the unknown ingredient is obviously a tafful being that it is being eaten without any knowledge of what it is?

If the answer to this is yes, it is obviously tafful, what happens before the next bite? Does the  proof of intention from his lack of knowledge from the get go continue even after the secret ingredient is discovered?

A related question. If someone has a chocolate covered snack platter in front of them, some compartments containing covered peanuts and some compartments containing raisins, but they are clearly separated.

Does the fact that the person is planning on eating both varieties, or that he grabs without checking which compartment he's grabbing from, prove that the chocolate is the Ikkur to him and the insides are Tafful?

Answer (score 1):

FIRST QUESTION

In the book [The Halochos of Brochos, p234](http://www.feldheim.com/halachos-of-brochos.html) Rabbi Bodner explains that if a person does not know what brocha to make a certain food, he should research the halachic authorities or ask a Rav. If he does not do so, he may not eat the food (unless  he bypasses the problem).

The problem here is that the person does not know what food he has. But he can determine what food it is by cutting open “the chocolate covered somethings”. I deduce therefore that he is obliged to do this.

Rabbi Bodner explains, p238, how to bypass the problem. The applicable suggestions in this situation are:

(suggestion 2) make a brocho on something else with the intention to cover the doubtful food
(suggestion 4) eat the food in the course of a meal.

In the “chocolate covered somethings” case, he could first make a brocho on a raisin and then on a carrot thereby covering all possibilities.

Indeed on p417, Rabbi Bodner writes about the view of Reb Moshe Feinstein  that he advised to do as follows. If he has another fruit he should make borei pri hoetz on that fruit with the intention to exempt the fruit in the candy. He should then make a shehakol on the candy. If he does not have another fruit, he should make a shehakol with specific intention not to cover the fruit and eat some of the chocolate covering. He should then recite a borei pri hoetz and eat the rest of the candy.

RELATED QUESTION

[Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Before_the_Bracha) says:

> 5) One should be careful to make brachot with kavana (the proper
>   intent) thinking about blessing with Hashem's name, who granted us
>   great kindness to allow one the fruit or bread one has. -snip-. Thus,
>   a person should make the bracha slowly and loud out in order to
>   inspire the requisite kavana.

It seems to me that he cannot have kavana when "he grabs without checking which compartment he's grabbing from". He should not do this.

Comment: That first chidush about not eating food of an unknown bracha is from the mishna berurah. While I appreciate the answer, I think it's missing the main point of my question. Can a person, through a lack of caring, cause a food to become a tafful? As a tafful it would not require a blessing so the point you raise will be moot. The same with the second point. We are discussing a case of haphazard eating which does not detract from his appreciation of Hashem's goodness. It just refocused (or re-unfocused)  his eating into having a tafful.